# Adding a website in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have taken  information from this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/estimating-parameters-in-linear-mixed-effects-models.html) for my project report. I want to add the website link in the "bibliography" section. But I don't know how is to cite this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using BibTeX? If so, what bibliography style?

Comment: @egreg I am writing the bibliography by using  ` \begin{thebibliography}` ` \end{thebibliography}`. I am not using natbib

Comment: Then `\bibitem{www} \url{http://the.url.for.the.site}` should do, shouldn't it? Add `\usepackage{url}` if not already in your preamble.

Comment: @egreg Could you please tell how can I minimize the font size of your code ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, sorry.